# monitor multiple pids with top

Tags: bash, process, monitoring, ps, top

I want to monitor memory usage for several processes and came up with a command like this:

```
ps aux |grep -e postgres -e unicorn -e nginx|cut -d' ' -f2|for i in $(xargs); do echo $i; done

16112
16113
...
```

How can I change the bit after the last pipe to feed arguments into `top -p $i`, so I get an of overall idea of memory consumption for all pids? The final command would produce something like `top -p<pid1> -p<pid2>` and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something like

```
pids=( $(pgrep 'postgres|unicorn|nginx') )
```

to put the PIDs in an array, and then

```
top "${pids[@]/#/-p }"
```

to spit them back out into `top`, prepending each with `-p`

Comment: very short and clever technique, this will prove useful for me in many scenarios